# Why do I receive syntax error when including BluetoothAPIs.h from Microsoft SDK?

Tags: c++, bluetooth, header-files, dev-c++

When I try to include `BluetoothAPIs.h`, the compiler shows me multiple syntax errors, e. g.:

```
[C++ Error] BluetoothAPIs.h(133): E2141 Declaration syntax error
[C++ Error] BluetoothAPIs.h(171): E2238 Multiple declaration for '__checkReturn'
...
```

This is `BluetoothAPIs.h` "invalid" part of code:

*Lines 132-138:*

```cpp
__checkReturn
HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND
WINAPI
BluetoothFindFirstRadio(
    __in const BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS * pbtfrp,
    __out HANDLE *                      phRadio
    );
```

*Lines 170-176:*

```cpp
__checkReturn
BOOL
WINAPI
BluetoothFindNextRadio(
    __in  HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND hFind,
    __out HANDLE * phRadio
    );
```

The .h file I took from Microsoft SDK.

### UPD 2021:

I never realised what really caused the error, but seems that using Visual Studio instead of Dev-C++ solves the problem. Now I'm wondering what should I change in order to get it to work in Dev-C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "The .h file I taked from Microsoft SDK.", do you mean:
a) SDK is installed on my machine and accessible in my IDE?
b) I picked up this file only?

If b) then you're missing a lot of files...

the first occurence of the macro __checkReturn is at line 132 of BluetoothAPIs.h, the one you mention...

Comment: thank you, but I have already found solution. I installed Visual Studio and now work under it.

Comment: Do you now, how to access SDK with other IDEs, example Dev-C++?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and don't know Dev-C++... but, anyway, there is probably a Settings (Compiler Settings? IDE Settings?) where you can enter the full path of "Include" folders (i.e SDK folder). Maybe you can add this path to the "PATH=" environnement variable of Windows...